# Ionic cordova admob plus consent

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, admob

I am trying to figure out how to use the consent plugin.

Following the documentation on https://admob-plus.github.io/docs/cordova/consent I can make it work to show the form and receive the status but it does not matter what I click in the form, the status does not change.

```
async checkConsent() {
    document.addEventListener(
      'deviceready',
      async () => {
        console.log(consent);
        if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
          const status = await consent.trackingAuthorizationStatus();
          /*
          trackingAuthorizationStatus:
          0 = notDetermined
          1 = restricted
          2 = denied
          3 = authorized
        */
          const statusNew = await consent.requestTrackingAuthorization();
        }

        const consentStatus = await consent.getConsentStatus();
        console.log('CONSENT STATUS:', consentStatus);
        await consent.requestInfoUpdate();
        console.log('CONSENT STATUS:', consentStatus);
        // if (consentStatus === consent.ConsentStatus.Required) {
        //   await consent.requestInfoUpdate();
        // }

        const formStatus = await consent.getFormStatus();
        console.log('FORM STATUS: ', formStatus);
        if (formStatus === consent.FormStatus.Available) {
          const form = await consent.loadForm();
          let result = await form.show();
          console.log(result);
        }
      },
      false,
    );
  }
```

Anyone can help here?

Best regards,
nosTa

Comment: Does it happen on all platforms? Also, what version of Ionic are you using?

Comment: Only tested on android so far. Using Ionic 5 with Angular 12.